# Is there a way to achieve real transparency with ToolboxBitmap?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, user-controls, toolbox

I'm creating icons for my usercontrols using Paint.NET. I'd like to have proper transparency like 32 bit PNG or [BMPX](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/11201-alpha-32bits-bitmap-support-for-paintnet/) provides. Is there a way to achieve that? Looking at the toolbox, the regular `Label` control does seem to use a fully transparent icon (unless MS assumes an always white toolbox background?).

Currently I'm embedding my icons as bitmaps compiled to embedded resource, and use the [`ToolboxBitmapAttribute(Type, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eth0sx9d.aspx) constructor. I tried using ICO or PNG or BMPX, but none of those work at all, they don't even get displayed, whereas a simple BMP does get displayed (using the lower left corner pixel color as transparent color).

Comment: *Real* transparency? No. But faked transparency works just fine, if you use a bitmap. Hans explains all the details below.

Comment: Thanks. Pity though, I've come to appreciate the AntiAliasing capabilities of PDN over the last months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Winforms toolbox bitmaps use Color.Fuchsia as the background color.  A pretty standard choice as the Bitmap.MakeTransparent() color, it is a nice fuchsed up color that is unlikely to cause unintended transparency in the rest of the image.  Here's the one for the Label control, retrieved from the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly:

[image]

It got turned into a PNG while uploading it, it is actually a BMP.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea how to extract the original image from System.Windows.Forms, otherwise I'd probably have checked that first. I remember that color from the VB6 days, it was used for the same purpose back then as well.